# Excel formulas - multiple conditions in multiple columns

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, formulas

I have Excel table as shown below. What formula should I write in order to get result as shown in row 15 (below screenshot).

Example: I would like to get value (`column E`) for `Car ID=1`, Paid (`column F`) with service date (`column B`) in range from `03/07/2017-30 days` to `03/07/2017`

Or if it makes easier for you: I would like to get `value` for `car ID=1` with `Paid=Yes` and `Service date>1/07/2017-30`

[image]

Sample Excel spreadsheet can be downloaded [here](https://ufile.io/im3gv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entered as an array formula using Ctrl+Shift+Enter:

```
=OFFSET(E1,
        MATCH(1,(A2:A12=B$15)*
                (F2:F12="Yes")*
                (B2:B12>($C$15-30))*
                (B2:B12<=$C$15)),0)
```